# Gradient Vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the rate of change of the temperature at the point P(0,0,0) in the direction toward the point (5,1,-2).

For the unit vector , I've seen two answers, one is u = <5,1,-2> and the other is $1/\sqrt{30}$ <5,1,-2>. I don't know which one is correct. When do we know it's a v and when it's a u?

Thanks all!

Comment: A "unit vector" is a vector whose norm is $1$.  So $\langle 5,1,-2 \rangle$ is not a unit vector, because its norm is $\sqrt{30}$.

Comment: Are you asking how do you know if a vector is a **unit** vector?

Comment: yes. I'm confused on that.

Comment: also, I don't know which answer is the correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A vector is a unit vector if it's magnitude/norm is equal to 1.

To find the magnitude of a vector, simply divide the vector by the sums of the squares of each component. This process is called normalization of a vector.

e.g. To normalize the vector v = <2,3,4> into a unit vector, first find it's magnitude -> $2^2$+$3^2$+$4^2$=4+9+16=29. Thus, the unit vector for v would then be 1/29 <2,3,4> (since you need to divide by 29 in order for the magnitude to equal 1)

So, which one of your vectors u has magnitude (or norm) equal to 1?